# How to Output to a Log File

Tags: powershell

How can I output the screen results to a txt file when I run this code?

```
#removes disabled clinical or corp accounts from SGs in the I-Drive OU

$searchOU = "OU=I-Drive,OU=SAS,OU=Application Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Enterprise,DC=z,DC=x,DC=y"

Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $searchOU | ForEach-Object{ $group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Get-ADUser | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $false} | ForEach-Object{ $user = $_
        $uname = $user.Name
        $gname = $group.Name
        Write-Host "Removing $uname from $gname" -Foreground Yellow
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output of [`Get-ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps) to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) like so:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $searchOU | ForEach-Object{
  $group = $_
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false} | ForEach-Object{
      $user = $_
      $uname = $user.Name
      $gname = $group.Name
      Write-Host "Removing $uname from $gname" -Foreground Yellow
      Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false
  }
} | Set-Content filename.txt
```

If you want any additional output (warnings, verbose, errors) [change the last line a bit to redirect the other streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610934/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-variable-up-to-place-output-to-stdout-or-null/58615047#58615047):

```
} *>&1 | Set-Content filename.txt
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [built-in transcript logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6) to log everything to a file as well just call one of the following from within your script:

```
Start-Transcript
```

or if you want the log to go to a specific place:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "\Path\To\LogFile.log"
```

Note that transcript logging is more useful in scripts than during an interactive session.

Comment: Thanks!  This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

- Store the value you'd like to log in a variable say $abc
- Write to log file and keep appending `$abc | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Somewhere\log.txt" -Append -Encoding UTF8`

Refer - [Log output of ForEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322588/log-output-of-foreach-loop)